# 404 error code returned when connecting via ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

Running ansible playbook, and trying to connect to Windows VMs. I can connect but I get 404 return code for some reason. I think my configuration is correct.

I have set up WINRM listeners:

`winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener`

```
Listener

Address = *
Transport = HTTP
Port = 5985
Hostname
Enabled = true
URLPrefix = wsman
CertificateThumbprint
ListeningOn = 15.137.1.188, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::200:5efe:15.137.1.188%4, fe80::4452:f5a1:54d2:90fd%3

Listener
Address = *
Transport = HTTPS
Port = 5986
Hostname = TPL-W2K16V1
Enabled = true
URLPrefix = wsman
CertificateThumbprint = 194ED0EF338220477D224F7025EF1BB915728F07
ListeningOn = 15.137.1.188, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::200:5efe:15.137.1.188%4, fe80::4452:f5a1:54d2:90fd%3
```

**This is the service configuration**

```
Service
RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
MaxConnections = 300
MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
AllowUnencrypted = true
Auth
    Basic = true
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = false
    CredSSP = false
    CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
DefaultPorts
    HTTP = 5985
    HTTPS = 5986
IPv4Filter = *
IPv6Filter = *
EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
CertificateThumbprint
AllowRemoteAccess = true
```

**Ansible variables**

```
ansible_user:$some_user
ansible_password: $some_pass
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_transport: basic
```

**When running the playbook I get:**

```
Using module file /home/hynek/ansible-env/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/ansible-2.8.3-py2.7.egg/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<$hostname> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: $user on PORT 5985 TO qa-cs-w-ctrl
fatal: [$hostname]: UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "plaintext: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 404",
"unreachable": true
```

}

Comment: maybe you could look at this troubleshooting winrm page : http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Ansible-project/MLjo5hsncNA) , good (bad) old proxy was to blame, respectively transport.py in winrm package. To set pywinrm no longer check your local env for a proxy, set session.trust_env to False.

```
# configure proxies from HTTP/HTTPS_PROXY envvars
    #session.trust_env = True
    session.trust_env = False
```